# VOIP notification is being missing or delay

Tags: xcode, voip, ios13, swift4.2

How do I know that my device is blocked from receiving VoIP notifications?

The application stops receiving VoIP notifications after receiving for 3-4 times. I understand that from iOS 13 VoIP notifications should be reported to CallKit. Even after reporting to CallKit, I'm going through this issue of not receiving VoIP notifications.

We have set apns-expiration to 0 and the priority to immediately(10).

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        dictPayload = payload.dictionaryPayload[K.KEY.APS] as? [String : Any]
        if dictPayload![K.KEY.ALERTTYPE] as? String == K.KEY.VOIPCALL {
            self.displayIncomingCall(uuid: appDelegate.uudiForCall, handle: (self.dictPayload!["handle"] as? String)!) { (error) in
            }
            CallProviderDelegate.sharedInstance.callDidReceiveIncomingCallfromKill(callInfo: self.dictPayload!)
        } else if dictPayload![K.KEY.ALERTTYPE] as? String == K.KEY.PUSHTOTALK {
            isPTTON = true
            pjsua_set_no_snd_dev()
            CallHandler.sharedCallManager()?.muteCall(true)
            CallHandler.sharedCallManager()?.setAudioSessionSpeaker()
            CallProviderDelegate.sharedInstance.callDidReceivePTTFromKIll(callFromName: dictPayload!["title"]  as? String, callfromExt: dictPayload![K.KEY.BODY] as? String)
        } else if dictPayload![K.KEY.ALERTTYPE] as? String == K.KEY.HANGUP {
            isPTTON = false
            CallProviderDelegate.sharedInstance.endCallFromPTT(endCallUDID: appDelegate.uudiForCall)
        }
    }


func displayIncomingCall(
        uuid: UUID,
        handle: String,
        hasVideo: Bool = false,
        completion: ((Error?) -> Void)?
    ) {
        let update = CXCallUpdate()
        update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value:(handle))
        CallProviderDelegate.sharedInstance.provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update, completion: { error in })
    }
```

XCODE: 11.3.1,
SWIFT: 4.2 &
iOS: 13.0 +

I am trying to figure out this issue since the last 2 months but not able to resolve it. Please help me

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You need to call completion block every time in pushRegistry method, in any case. When you call completion, system understand you have processed payload successfully, and reported to callkit.

Comment: Everything is as per apple doc. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit
But still, I am not able to receive it after x time.

Comment: Completion not handled. See in your given link, there is a line, // Tell PushKit that the notification is handled.
            completion()

Comment: Yes, @Max. I have updated my code and till now it's working fine but I will update the final response here after a few days and thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it seems that you aren't reporting a new incoming call for every VoIP push notification. It's true that when there is an active CallKit call, you can receive VoIP pushes without reporting a new incoming call, but it's not as simple as it might seem. Since CallKit and PushKit are asynchronous, you are not guaranteed that when you receive a push of type `K.KEY.PUSHTOTALK` or `K.KEY.HANGUP` the call has already started. Moreover, if `dictPayload` is nil, you fail to report a new incoming call.

Anyway, I think that the biggest problem in your code is that you're not calling the completion handler of the `pushRegistry(:didReceiveIncomingPushWith...)` method. You should do the following:

```
self.displayIncomingCall(uuid: appDelegate.uudiForCall, handle: (self.dictPayload!["handle"] as? String)!) { (error) in
    completion() // <---
}
```

and

```
CallProviderDelegate.sharedInstance.provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update, completion: { error in
    completion()
})
// or
CallProviderDelegate.sharedInstance.provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update, completion: completion)
```

Comment: I have modified my code but noticed one weird case like VOIP is not working in mobile data. :(

Comment: Do you mean VoIP pushes? If yes, it shouldn't be related to the code. Maybe you just have an unreliable mobile data connection.

Comment: Basically VOIP is missing when I do off & on the mobile data but it's started again if I change the network. :(

Comment: Just try with a reliable network connection. If it always works, then there's nothing wrong in your code. An unreliable connection will prevent you from receive some notifications, it's normal and unavoidable.

Comment: Now it stops in even in wi-fi. Would you like to do code-level-support?

Comment: If it stops after you've received some calls, it means that you fail to report new incoming calls some times. Have you fixed all the cases I've mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Macro, I have updated my code and it's good till now but I will update my final response in a few days, and thanks a lot for your help. :)